# Pegar múltiplos valores de um multi select

Tags: php

Estou precisando pegar valores de um multiselect

```
<select id="opcoes" name="opcoes[]" class="select" multiple="multiple" size="5" data-required required="required">
<option value="opcao1">Opção 1</option>
<option  value="opcao2">Opção 2</option>
<option  value="opcao3">Opção 3</option>
```

Gostaria de saber como posso pegar o valores selecionados e colocar numa variável do php.

Já tentei com `$_POST['opcoes[]']`, mas sempre retorna null para mim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para chamar todas as opções selecionadas faça apenas `$_POST['opcoes']`, nome do select deve ter colchetes e o atributo `multiple` para funcionar corretamente.

```
<form method="post" action="#">
   <select id="opcoes" name="opcoes[]" multiple="multiple" >
      <option value="opcao1">Opção 1</option>
      <option  value="opcao2">Opção 2</option>
      <option  value="opcao3">Opção 3</option>
   </select>

   <input type="submit" />
</form>

<?php
   foreach($_POST['opcoes'] as $item){
      echo $item .'<br>';   
   }
```

No código de produção não esqueça de fazer um verificação se existem itens marcados, pode usar a função `count()` para evitar o envio de um null no foreach.

Answer (score 2):

Você não precisa colocar `[]`.

Exemplo funcionando:

> HTML

```
 <form method="POST" action="../../model/php/teste.php" >
    <select id="opcoes" name="opcoes[]" class="select" multiple="multiple" size="5" data-required required="required">
       <option value="opcao1">Opção 1</option>
       <option  value="opcao2">Opção 2</option>
       <option  value="opcao3">Opção 3</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
 </form>
```

> PHP

```
var_dump($_POST['opcoes']);
```

Comment: Não entendi, precisa ou não dos `colchetes`? na resposta fala que não mas no código eles estão :)

Comment: @rray Na resposta ele se refere ao que já tentou como `$_POST['opcoes[]']` mas na verdade não há necessidade  da utilização, sendo que `$_POST['opcoes']` já retornaria o array.

Comment: Aaaaaah aquele colchetes hehe, agora entendi.

Comment: rray e Gabriel Rodrigues, obg pela ajuda. Me esclareceram o que eu precisava. Eu usei os colchetes porque pensei que ao pegar mais de uma opção no select, eu estaria trabalhando com um array, então por isso coloquei (também tinha pesquisado isso e algumas fontes de pesquisa indicaram o uso do colchete).  vlw galera!